# Detected Guava issue #1635 which indicates that a version of Guava less than 16.01 is in use

Tags: apache-spark, guava, datastax, emr

I am running spark job on emr and using datastax connector to connect to cassandra cluster. I am facing issues with the guava jar please find the details as below
I am using below cassandra deps

```
cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.1 | CQL spec 3.3.1
```

Running spark job on EMR 4.4 with below maven deps

org.apache.spark
    spark-streaming_2.10
    1.5.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId><dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>

    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

facing issues when i submit spark job as below

```
ava.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.clusterBuilder(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:35)
       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:87)
       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:153)
       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
      at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
       at ampush.event.process.core.CassandraServiceManagerImpl.getAdMetaInfo(CassandraServiceManagerImpl.java:158)
       at ampush.event.config.metric.processor.ScheduledEventAggregator$4.call(ScheduledEventAggregator.java:308)
       at ampush.event.config.metric.processor.ScheduledEventAggregator$4.call(ScheduledEventAggregator.java:290)
       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:222)
       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:222)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:902)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:902)
       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected Guava issue #1635 which indicates that a version of Guava less than 16.01 is in use.  This introduces codec resolution issues and potentially other incompatibility issues in the driver.  Please upgrade to Guava 16.01 or later.
       at com.datastax.driver.core.SanityChecks.checkGuava(SanityChecks.java:62)
       at com.datastax.driver.core.SanityChecks.check(SanityChecks.java:36)
       at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:67)
       ... 23 more
```

please let me know how to manage guava deps here ?

Thanks

Comment: Your dependency blocks are incomplete

Answer (score 10):

Another solution, Go to directory

> spark/jars

. Rename `guava-14.0.1.jar` then copy `guava-19.0.jar` like this picture:

[image]

Comment: As a note, Guava 20 won't work for this. Guava 19 does work, though.

Comment: Such a great hack!

Comment: Renaming the old jar and adding the new one didn't work for me (spark 2.4.0). 
Removing the old jar resolved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem, and resolved it by using the maven Shade plugin to shade the guava version that the Cassandra connector brings in.

I needed to exclude the Optional, Present and Absent classes explicitly because I was running into issues with Spark trying to cast from the non-shaded Guava Present type to the shaded Optional type. I'm not sure if this will cause any problems later on, but it seems to be working for me for now.

You can add this to the `<plugins>` section in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>
                    shade
                </goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>fat</shadedClassifierName>

        <relocations>
            <relocation>
                <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                <shadedPattern>shaded.guava</shadedPattern>
                <includes>
                    <include>com.google.**</include>
                </includes>

                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com.google.common.base.Optional</exclude>
                    <exclude>com.google.common.base.Absent</exclude>
                    <exclude>com.google.common.base.Present</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </relocation>
        </relocations>

        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This will not solve the purpose here. The reason here is our deployment platform EMR. The way emr uses to build default classpath of spark is using less < 16 version of guava in classpath which is due to the fact that it pulls hadoop libraries which are still old with EMR 4.2\4.4\4.6.  I have fixed mine by adding bootstrap process to emr to override default spark classpath with updated one.

Comment: I confirm this does fix the issue for me on a Spark Standalone v1.5.2 cluster and Spark Cassandra connector v1.5.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the the same issue while retrieving records from Cassandra table using Spark (java) on Spark submit.

Please check your **guava** jar version used by Hadoop and Spark in cluster using **find** command and change it accordingly.

```
find / -name "guav*.jar"
```

Otherwise add **guava** jar externally during **spark-submit** for driver and executer  **spark.driver.extraClassPath** and **spark.executor.extraClassPath** respectively.

```
spark-submit --class com.my.spark.MySparkJob --master local --conf 'spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048' --conf 'spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level=ONE' --conf 'spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level=ONE' --conf 'spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false' --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=lib/guava-19.0.jar" --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=lib/guava-19.0.jar" --total-executor-cores 15 --executor-memory 15g  --jars $(echo lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') target/my-sparkapp.jar
```

It's working for me. Hope you can try it.

Answer (score 2):

Just add in your POM's `<dependencies>` block something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

(or any version > 16.0.1 that you prefer)

Comment: i was going through the link https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/HnTsWJkI5jo which says Spark 1.5 uses Guava 14, Cassandra driver core requires Guava 16. The spark cassandra connetor rises an exception. so how adding above would solve my issue may be a newbie question. thanks

Comment: Also as per link https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector i am using 1.5 cassandra connector 1.5, 1.6 (spak) 3.0 (cassandra) ? not sure then why i am getting issue

Comment: Not sure what you were asking.  If you are interested to know why Maven resolved the old version of Guava, you may use `mvn dependency:tree` which it shows you how every dependency is resolved (or ignored) transitively

Comment: I got the root cause the problem i mentioned here is related to EMR. Here spark and cassandra are trying to use guava 16 and EMR is adding old hadoop lib to spark classpath fetching old  guava 11. I am working  with another request with amazon to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Oh man I wish it was that easy. For me, spark itself has a ton of jars. The screen shot above almost works, but for our version of spark we had different versions of guava all over the place. I ended up just filtering them all out, like everywhere. And I added the stuff in the classpath like @adri

Comment: @TonyFraser That's what `<dependencyManagement>` comes handy.  Have `spark` declared in `dependencyManagement` of your parent POM, having trouble dependencies excluded.  By doing so, POMs inheriting from your parent POM, when declaring `spark` as dependency, will have those trouble dependencies excluded.  Of course you need to add the corresponding correct dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this by adding the guava 16.0.1 jar externally and then specifying the class-path on Spark submit with help of below configuration values:

**--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/guava-16.0.1.jar"
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/guava-16.0.1.jar"**

Hope this helps someone with similar error !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Adrian for your response.

I am on a little of a different architecture than everybody else on the thread but the Guava problem is still the same. I am using spark 2.2 with mesosphere. In our development environment we use sbt-native-packager to produce our docker images to pass into mesos.

Turns out, we needed to have a different guava for the spark submit executors than we need for the code that we run on the driver. This worked for me.

build.sbt

```
....
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "19.0" force(),
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.3" excludeAll (
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.hadoop", name = "hadoop-common"), //this is for s3a
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.google.guava",  name= "guava" )),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"   excludeAll (
    ExclusionRule("org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged", name="jersey-guava"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.google.guava",  name= "guava" )) ,
  "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.7.0"  excludeAll (
    ExclusionRule("org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged", name="jersey-guava"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.google.guava",  name= "guava" )) ,
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.6",
...
dockerCommands ++= Seq(
...
  Cmd("RUN rm /opt/spark/dist/jars/guava-14.0.1.jar"),
  Cmd("RUN wget -q http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.jar  -O /opt/spark/dist/jars/guava-23.0.jar")
...
```

When I tried to replace guava 14 on the executors with guava 16.0.1 or 19, it still wouldn't work. Spark submit just died. My fat jar which is actually the guava that is in use for my application in the driver I forced to be 19, but my spark submit executor I had to replace to be 23. I did try replacing to 16 and 19, but spark just died there too.

Sorry for diverting, but every time after all my google searches this one came up every time. I hope this helps other SBT/mesos folks too.