# Hbase 1.1.2 compatible Cassandra version - Guava Jar version issue

Tags: cassandra, hbase, guava, hortonworks-data-platform

Trying to read data from `HBase` table and do some process and populate the data in `Cassandra`.

Facing problem with `Guava` Jar version, we are bounded to `HBase version 1.1.2`, which supports `Guava 12.x version`, But Cassandra is expecting latest version's of Guava more than 16 Version.

**Update:** 
The reason we need to use HBase 1.1.2 is because we are going to use HDP 2.4.2 version , which supports HBase 1.1.2 version.

Comment: Can't you really upgrade Guava manually in HDP to 16.0.1 or higher? The Cassandra Java driver cannot work with older versions. See this SO question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877897/detected-guava-issue-1635-which-indicates-that-a-version-of-guava-less-than-16.

Comment: @adutra : The problem is HBase 1.1.2 supports only Guava 12.x version.